api-platform - get ManyToOne related objects referenced with IRI in json-format-response
I tried to setup a api-platform server but ran in to a problem. Related entities are only referenced by IRI if the response is JSON-LD or the the containing entity is also exposed via ApiResource
given the following entity classes
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
#[Groups(['A::read'])]
class A
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(
        mappedBy: 'a',
        targetEntity: B::class,
        cascade: ['persist', 'remove'],
        orphanRemoval: true
    )]
    private Collection $b;


    // ....
}

// I don't want to expose this via API. this is an entity that does not make sense on its own
#[ApiResource]
#[Groups(['A::read'])]
#[ORM\Entity]
class B
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: X::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private X $x;

    // ....
}

#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity]
class X
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    #[ORM\Column(
        type: Types::SMALLINT
    )]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 45, unique: true, nullable: false)]
    private string $name;

    // ....
}

and the following api_platform.yaml (default with json as result format)
api_platform:
    title: Hello API Platform
    version: 1.0.0
    formats:
        json: ['application/json']
    docs_formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        jsonopenapi: ['application/vnd.openapi+json']
        html: ['text/html']
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
        extra_properties:
            standard_put: true
            rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
        pagination_enabled: false
    event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: false
    keep_legacy_inflector: false


this will return the followning json
{
   "id":11,
   "b":[
      {
         "id":22,
         "x":"/api/x/99"
      },
      {
         "id":44,
         "x":"/api/x/88"
      }
   ]
}

but this only works if I expose B over it's own enpoint with #[ApiResource] . I don't want this because B does not make sense with being part of A
If I remove #[ApiResource], the result will look like this
{
   "id":11,
   "b":[
      {
         "id":22,
         "x":[]
      },
      {
         "id":44,
         "x":[]
      }
   ]
}

I did not have this issue when I set the format to json-ld
What can I do to fix this?
